# Can we define font of two text strings outside in a variable to be used in tkinter widgets using concatenation?

Tags: python, string, button, tkinter, fonts

I'm willing to do this kind of thing.

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

t1="Visit Us:"
t2="www.something.com"
```

Here if I can configure the font descriptors for t1 and t2 separately...then it'll be helpful!

```
Button(root, text=t1+t2, command=Visit).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do what you want. The only widgets which support different fonts for different parts of a string are the `Canvas` and `Text` widgets.